# Changing the background-Image using Jquery causing a flickering kind of effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Following is the portion of the script which I am using to create a slider by changing the background image for every imageobject I have for a cycle of time.

```
   #Sliderimg - height is 500px,

   $("#Sliderimg").css({
        "background-image": "url(../Images/" +SliderImageObj.image + ")",
        "display": "block",
        "z-index": "50px"
    });
```

What could have gone wrong with this as I'm getting the flickering effect every time I change the image, My problem is not with the new image about to load, its flickering(flashing on to the bottom of the screen) for the old image which is about to be replaced.

Comment: Why are you setting the display and z-index attributes every time you want to update the background image?  Best toove the display and z-index attributes to your CSS.  Also z-index:50px is invalid.  z-index takes an integer value.

Comment: Are you pre-loading your images? If not, the flicker could be whilst the browser is downloading.

Comment: You might find the flash is caused whilst the new image loads. If this is the case, consider [pre-loading the images.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images)

Comment: @Lokase I couldn't avoid the display property..

Comment: @Grigor  I couldn't capture the screenshot as it is happening in a flash of seconds

Comment: My problem is not with the new image about to load, its flickering for the old image which is about to be replaced

Comment: sorry I don't get what you mean by flickering

Comment: @Grigor Its like the background image to be replaced is flashing on the bottom of the screen before the background is set with the new image

Comment: use animation plugin instead of css plugin

Answer (score 1):

You see a flicker because every time you change the background image, your browser has to download it before it can show the background. If the images aren't too big (more than say, 5kb) you can try caching them in the browser by applying them to elements where they won't show up.

Also, 50px isn't a valid z-index, that property requires integers only.

Comment: Not true, a proper browser will cache the images whilst cycling and remember those, battling the download delay. the flicker comes from the way browsers redraw items.

Comment: My problem is not with the new image about to load, its flickering for the old image which is about to be replaced

Comment: It might help to have a more specific example, since it's slightly difficult to tell exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe delete "px" from your z-index atribute? It take decimal values.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis Thanks :) but nobody appreciated that :P

Comment: I agree with you guys, I have corrected that, but i still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

the browser is forced to redraw the entire background.

how this is done is by setting background to white and then redrawing the new background.

use jquery.animate() to battle this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the other day. Oddly enough, it seemed to be OK in FF, but would flicker in IE, Chrome, and sometimes Safari. The solution is to use a css sprite sheet. You create an image that has both backgrounds next to each other. You only show a portion of the background sheet. you toggle it by adjusting the margin on the background. You can handle the margin adjustments using addClass and removeClass. Below is code, see here for a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fMhMY/

**CSS**

```
.navButton span{
width:32px;
height:32px;
display:block;
}

a.leftButton span, a#leftButton span{
background-image:url(Prev.png);
background-position:-64px 0px;
}

/*nav button sprites */

/*sprite order is pushed, hover, natural */

a.leftButton.navOver span, a.rightButton.navOver span{
background-position:-32px 0px;
}

a.leftButton.navPressed span, a.rightButton.navPressed span{
background-position:0px 0px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style='display:inline-block'>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="leftButton navButton" id='lefty'>
        <span></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.leftButton').mousedown(function() {

        $('.leftButton').addClass('navPressed');
        console.log('mousedown');

});
$('.leftButton').mouseup(function() {
        $('.leftButton').removeClass('navPressed');
        console.log('mouseup');
});

$('.leftButton').hover(function() {
        $('.leftButton').addClass('navOver');
        console.log('hover');
});


$('.leftButton').mouseout(function() {
        $('.leftButton').removeClass('navPressed').removeClass('navOver');
        console.log('mouseout');
});
```