# HTML hidden image - how to download and size before revealing?

Tags: javascript, html, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript Preloading Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images)

I am using JS to set img.hidden=false some time after the page has loaded.  This causes the image to download and resizes the img element - which I would like to avoid (I am using inline style width:2em to size the image).  Secondly when I change the img source, there is a slight delay as the second image downloads.

How can I download my images prior to showing them on the page...?

Comment: `display: none` on the css?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images

Answer (score 2):

First download the image and then trigger the action, in this way with jquery:

```
  var i = document.createElement('img'); // or new Image()
  // may be you need to set the element id...
  i.id = 'your id';
  // here handle on load event
  $(i).load(function() {

       // finally the new image is loaded, you can trigger your action
       $('#container').append($(this));

  });
  // This is the last step, set the url and start the image download.
  i.src = 'http://www.hostname.com/yourimage.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery (if needed):

```
var imageNode = new Image(); // or document.createElement('img');

imageNode.onload = function(e) {
    // Code for appending to the DOM
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(this);
};

imageNode.src = 'path/to/image.jpg';
```

---

If your img tag does already exist like this:

```
<img id='myimg' alt=''>
```

In JavaScript use:

```
var imageNode = document.getElementById('myimg');
```

Instead of:

```
var imageNode = new Image();
```

*Keep in mind that the code needs to be executed after the img tag or when the DOM is ready/loaded. Otherwise it does not exist when the code is executing*

Comment: I was just wondering to know how to do this without jquery :)

Comment: How do I tie this to the <img> tag in my html?

Comment: Ok, I have edited a bit for more clarification on how to use this with an existing img tag. Please check if it is of any help.