# image.onload into a method

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas, typescript

So I've been trying to get an image preloader to work, as I've understood that I need to load the images before I can draw them on the canvas. I've followed this description: [How do image preloaders work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578521/how-do-image-preloaders-work/30581295#30581295) but I'm unsure about how to make the `img.onload` into a method, or somehow make a workaround, as the function can't access the variables it's supposed to.

Here's my code. Canvas class isn't included as it's irrelevant.
Thanks in advance.

```
    window.onload = function () {
        var MyApp = new App();
        MyApp.Initialize();
    }
    class App {
        canvas: Canvas;
        imageURLs: string[] = [];
        images = [];
        imagePreLoader: ImagePreLoader;
        constructor() {
            this.canvas = new Canvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, "mainCanvas");
            this.ImagePreLoader = new ImagePreLoader(this.imageURLs, this.images);
        }
        Initialize() {
            this.imageURLs.push("0.png");
            this.imageURLs.push("1.png");
            this.imagePreLoader.startLoadingAllImages(this.Loop.bind(this));
        }
        Loop() {
            this.canvas.clear();
            this.Draw();
            requestAnimationFrame(this.Loop.bind(this));
        }
        Draw() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
                this.canvas.drawImage(this.images[i], i * 100, 100);
            }
        }
    }
    class ImagePreLoader {
        imagesLoaded = 0;
        imageURLs: string[];
        images;
        constructor(urlArray: string[], imageArray) {
            this.imageURLs = urlArray;
            this.images = imageArray;
        }
        startLoadingAllImages(callback): void {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.imageURLs.length; i++) {
                var img = new Image();
                this.images.push(img);
                img.onload = function () { //This doesn't work as the function can't access the variables of the class.
                    this.imagesLoaded++;
                    if (this.imagesLoaded >= this.imageURLs.length) {
                        callback();
                    }
                }
                img.src = this.imageURLs[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change :

```
img.onload = function () { //This doesn't work as the function can't access the variables of the class.
    this.imagesLoaded++;
    if (this.imagesLoaded >= imageURLs.length) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

to:

```
img.onload = () => { 
    this.imagesLoaded++;
    if (this.imagesLoaded >= imageURLs.length) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

using a lambda, i.e. `() => { ... }`, makes the `this` keyword work as expected in this situation. A `function` will get its scope (`this`) from the caller giving it a faulty scope in this case.

Comment: Thanks!, this works, but what's the difference between `= function ()` and `= () =>` ?

Comment: You can read more about it here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-lambdas-and-using-39this39

Comment: beautiful. Also explained shortly but accurately. Thanks