# Delay JS code until CSS background image loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I have a JS script that works with an HTML canvas to:

1. draw a background image onto the canvas element, and
2. draw lines/other information onto the canvas.
   (It's for dimensional measurements on furniture).

However, when moving the script from local to a live site, I believe the loading time of the image is throwing off the script.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmyhvneu/) example

The chunk of the code that deals with image loading:

```
this.sbCanvasElement = $('#'+CanvasDOMRef);
var can = document.getElementById(CanvasDOMRef);
this.sbCanvas = can.getContext('2d');

this.sbCanvasElement.css("background-image","url('"+this.sbImage+"')");
this.sbCanvasElement.css("background-positon","0px 0px");
```

This section of the script grabs the Canvas element and sets the background image to the URL previously stored in the object.

The result can either be

- Successful

  [image: Screenshot of success]
- Failure

  [image: Screenshot of failure]

I believe I have to interrupt the script while the image is loaded, but I am not sure of the best approach. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use an image preloader to be sure both your images are loaded before you try to use the images. Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578521/how-do-image-preloaders-work).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onload` event for the image, but you need to change the `css()` method with `drawImage()` canvas method.

```
  var imageObj = new Image();
  var context = this.sbCanvas;
  var coord = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, coord.x, coord.y);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'your-image-url.jpg';
```