# Speed up drawing image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, drawimage

I have to draw multiple images on one canvas. I make a program that works, though, I have to speed up the display. I see images appear one by one:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('images_tiles').getContext('2d');
function handler() {
    var i = this.i;
    ctx.drawImage(this.img_src, this.r * tileSize, this.c*tileSize,  tileSize * tileList[i].qw, tileSize * tileList[i].qh);
}


//Draw tiles in spiral
for (i=0; i<tileList.length; i++)
{
    var o = { img_src: new Image, c: tileList[i].y, r: tileList[i].x, i: i };
    o.img_src.onload = handler.bind(o);
    o.img_src.src =  './viewer/images/'+path+'/LOD'+glod+'/tiles_'+ o.c + '_' + o.r +'.jpeg';
}
```

I see Webworker can make parallelization but not for display. So do you have a solution or/and a trick.

Comment: You are displaying the image as they load, loading images is relatively slow.  You should wait until they have all loaded, then display them.

Comment: This with not improve the speed, just draw the images in the same time instead of one by one ?

Comment: The browser can draw 100s of medium sized images every 60th of a second, but it can not do this if you are loading them from an external source such as a Hard drive, Networks, or other mass storage sources.

Comment: [Preload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578521/how-do-image-preloaders-work/30581295#30581295) all of your images before you try to draw any of them.

Comment: Can we preload images in background ? For me the preloading will just draw all the images at the same time, but it will take the same time to have all theimages, isn't it ?