# Pre-load animated gif for hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have the following images:

[**Static Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Kgi.png) | [**Starting Animation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14qMg.gif) | [**Ending Animation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwJ0.gif)

And I am using the following code ([jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yL5hbzxq/2/)):

**HTML**

```
<div id="link">
  <div id="link-gif">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#link-gif {
   width:150px;
   height:40px;
   border:1px solid #39464E;
   background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4Kgi.png'); /*static*/
   background-size:contain;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:bottom center;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $("#link-gif").hover(
        function() {
            /* starting animation */
            $(this).css("background-image", "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/14qMg.gif')");
        },
        function() {
            /* ending animation */
            $(this).css("background-image", "url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwJ0.gif')");
        }                         
    );                  
});
```

So in summary, what happens is: I first load the static image. When someone hover's over the `#link-gif`, the starting animation gif starts, and when you hover off of it, the ending animation starts.

My real question is, how do I make sure these gif's are loaded before someone hovers over the image? The first time someone hovers, it is a little glitchy and then it get's better.

I did it this way so that it would work with the oldest browsers possible because I need at least IE8 support. If anyone has any better suggestions, I'm all for it.

Comment: You could load the images as normal, but in a DIV that is hidden or off screen.  Then the resource will be there.

Comment: You could also check this answer, that has many solutions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images