# It is possible to write a JavaScript procedure that pre-loads all images and videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Scenario:** I have a HTML/CSS/JavaScript slideshow whose slides are `div`s like

```
<div class="slide" id="slide1">
   ...
</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide2">
   ... 
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="slide" id="slideN">
   ... 
</div>
```

and these `div`s contain `img`s and `video`s and I what I want to do is pre-load these elements so that they'll already be up and showing when the user goes to the next slide. I'm wondering if there exists a general procedure for doing this, a procedure where I can add or substract media elements and it still works because the procedure doesn't rely on target a specific element's `src` attribute or something. From what I understand, it requires doing a hacky thing where you remove and then add back in the `src` attribute like

```
$(function(){
  var $images = $('.slide img'), 
      $videos = $('.slide video'), 
      k = 0,
      n = $images.length + $videos.length; 
  $images.each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src') = '';
    $(this).attr('src') = src;
    console.log(k++/n * 100 + "%"); 
  });
  $videos.each(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src') = '';
    $(this).attr('src') = src;
    console.log(k++/n * 100 + "%"); 
  });
  $('.slide').show(); // now we're ready!
});
```

Is that correct? Why or why not?

(On a related note, is it possible to merge two jQuery resulting sets, so that I don't have to write two `each` loops above?)

The way I've seen it done always involves an array of the URLs of images to be loaded, like the example

```
var images = [];
function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        images[i] = new Image();
        images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
}

//-- usage --//
preload(
    "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
    "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
    "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
)
```

from [JavaScript Preloading Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images)

and that just doesn't seem general enough to me.

Comment: `$('.slide img, .slide video')` will collect them both into one query.

Comment: As per your code browser should be triggering requests to load all images in the HTML. Can you check in your network tab is all images are loaded even without this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can load each one immediately and put them in a "bank" section with `display:none` set so they're invisible. The browser will cache them, and they'll be available to display as soon as you're ready.