# How can I fully load images before they are animated into the current viewport?

Tags: jquery, image, performance, viewport, image-preloader

at our new website we have a small problem. Look here:
http://dev.stadtkreation.com/klangmanufaktur/

If the page is loaded for the first time or after clearing the cache, the images appear too late when the page is scrolled horizontally (on landscape screen format on desktop screens). It seems that automatically they are only loaded when inside the viewport, so when animated into the visible are, the still need a moment to load.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards
joschi81

Comment: [How to preload images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

In Body part : set `overflow:hidden` property. so scroll are not shown and site will be looking nice.
ThankYou.