# How to load images after home page load

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web page that displays 100 images in slider. I wish to display only 10 images when page load. After page load, the remaining 90 images should display..

Comment: What slider you are using, refer to their documentation

Comment: you send only ten images from your php script, then in your js you run an ajax to load the rest

Answer (score 2):

This would be called image pre loading and usually can be done in JavaScript or jQuery to load the images before hand so your images will load faster. Here is a how-to guide on pre loading images.
 [JavaScript Preloading Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images) 
or checkout this guide which uses CSS and jQuery 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/image-preloader/

Here is an example in jQuery. Enjoy!

```
$.preloadImages = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    $("<img />").attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}

$.preloadImages("hoverimage1.jpg","hoverimage2.jpg");
```

Basically it calls these images to be used before the page is loaded and that will load the images into the cache making it faster when being called later in the browser.

Comment: Kindly provide an example to help the OP.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that :p

Answer (score -1):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
 //load rest of images here code
    });
```

Comment: Kindly provide an example and an explanation to the code.