# How can I preload images of B component in A component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, preload

Lets say I have two Vue files, A.vue and B.vue. Inside A there is a router-link that points to B, which contains a lot of images that I'm downloading from Firebase realtime database. Every first time I navigate from A to B the images don't load as fast as I need, so I need a way to preload those images in A.vue in order to have them all rendered in B.vue when I click the link.

What I have done so far is using a method `getUrls()` in the `mounted()` hook on A.vue to get the download url of the images and store them on `localStorage`, and by the time I've already got to B.vue, the `mounted()` hook inside B triggers the `setImage()` method which uses a `callback` function as an argument.

I've read about `router.BeforeEach()` navigation guards methods but I really don't know how to implement that and not really sure if that solves my problem.

My Code:

```
A.vue 
<template>
   <div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   methods:{
    getUrls: function(path, localStorage_id){
        var storage = Firebase.storage();
        var storageRef = storage.ref();
        var pathReference = storageRef.child(path);
        pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {  
            let localStorageId = localStorage_id;
            localStorage.setItem( localStorageId, url);
        }).catch(function(error) {

        });
     }
    },
   mounted(){
    this.getUrls("path/to/img", "img_id"); // this Is just for one image 
                                              (to keep it simple) 
   },
  }
</script>

B.vue
<template>
   <div>
    <img id="img_id"> 
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   methods:{
    setImage: function(localStorageId, imgId, setSrc){
        var imgURL = localStorage.getItem(localStorageId);
        console.log(imgURL);
        setSrc(imgId, imgURL);            
    },
    // callback function
    setSrc: function(imgId, imgURL){
        var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
        img.src = imgURL; 
    }
   },
   mounted(){
    this.setImage("localStorage_id", "img_id", this.setSrc); 
   },
  }
</script>
```

(ommitted `style` tags for simplicity)

I expect to be available to watch all images without having to wait (too long) but I don't get any speed up with what I've tried. Any suggestions?

Comment: I did it in router you can see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59419841/2045817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: if you want images quickly, store them locally.

The solution was simple. Because my images were so important for this app I had to store them locally in my app, instead of downloading them from the Firebase realtime database. That helped a lot with the rendering speed. So I created a dir with those files in my app and changed my setting methods to:

```
   setImage: function(my_imgURL, imgId, setSrc){
    var imgURL = my_imgURL; 
    console.log(imgURL);
    setSrc(imgId, imgURL);          
    },
    setSrc: function(imgId, imgURL){
        var img = document.getElementById(imgId);
        img.src = imgURL; 

    }
```