# Preloaded image not used warning in Vue.js application despite correct as attribute

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, performance, preload

I'm working on a Vue.js application and I'm trying to preload an image using the  tag. However, I keep getting a warning that says:

> The resource http://localhost:8085/img/secondGet.webp was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="preload" as="image" href="img/secondGet.webp">
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's how I'm using the image in my Vue component:

```
<div class="bg-white pt-12">
    <!-- onboard hero -->
    <Hero>
      <template #img>
        <img
          class="w-full h-full absolute object-cover bg-image"
          :src="require('../../public/img/secondGet.webp')"
          alt="main hero image background"
        />
      </template>
```

I've checked the following:

- The file path is correct and matches in both places.
- The image is not being loaded dynamically or conditionally.
- I'm not using lazy loading for this image.

Why am I still getting this warning, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe some of the answers of this question can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090443/how-to-preload-images-using-vue-js

Comment: Not really, those answers are more about preloading images within the Vue.js framework and don't directly tackle the issue that I'm facing with the preload link in the HTML head. Anyway, appreciate the suggestion & I already checked that link

Comment: Most probably you're getting this warning on Firefox. It's harmless and you don't need to worry about it if you're sure that image needs to be preloaded. Check if chrome/chromium based browsers throw same warning.

Comment: since you use `require('../../public/img/secondGet.webp')` you don't need to preload - the image is bundled into the code somehow