# TypeScript - Name "Image" Not Found

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an image loading class but in the array definition it throws an error saying `name "Image" not found`, despite creating an image object later in the code.

```
class ImageLoader {
static toLoadCount:number = 0;

private static images = Array<Image>();

static onAllLoaded() {};

static onImageLoad() {
    --Images.toLoadCount;

    if(Images.toLoadCount == 0)
        Images.onAllLoaded();
}

static load(path: string) {
    ++Images.toLoadCount;
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = "Images/" + path;
    img.onload = Images.onImageLoad;
    Images.images[path.substring(0, path.length - 4)] = img;
    return img;
}

static allImagesLoaded() {
    return (Images.toLoadCount == 0);
}

[key: string]: any;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Preloading Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. This is about Typescript compilation, not javascript browser loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of `new Image()` is `HTMLImageElement`, so correct typing for the array is
`images: Array<HTMLImageElement>` or `images: HTMLImageElement[]`:

```
class ImageLoader {
    static toLoadCount: number = 0;

    private static images: HTMLImageElement[] = [];

    static onAllLoaded() { };

    static onImageLoad() {
        --ImageLoader.toLoadCount;

        if (ImageLoader.toLoadCount == 0)
            ImageLoader.onAllLoaded();
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I unfortunately can't comment because I don't have enough rep but I just wanted to add one more thing to Aleksey L's solution.

Usually if you are using VS-Code or Webstorm or any editor that has intellisense you can hover over the "`new Image()`" and it will tell you the type of it.

So in this case you would have known that img is actually a HTMLImageElement:

```
let img: HTMLImageElement = new Image();
```

Then you would have immediately recognized that your array is incorrect as image is not of `type Image` but rather of type `HTMLImageElement` and you could have adjusted your array immediately to `HTMLImageElement[]`.

kr,
Georg

P.S.: I would love if you upvote this I hate to do this long posts instead of short comments.

Comment: Got upvote, so now you can comment I believe :). Also you can see types in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html)

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that I can hover over Image, I just still have C++ in my head so I thought that Image was a sort of wrapper. Thanks for the clarification!