# How can I display random images each time an element is hovered?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make different random images appear on each hover. When the mouse pointer goes away and hovers back to the element, I'd like a new image to appear. I've managed to allow an image to appear on mouse hover, but I can't get the image to be different on each new hover (without refreshing).

The image source is generated with PHP in and is shuffled, so I don't think I'll need multiple sources.

jsfiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6cn9xgz8/

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```html
  <a class="onhover-toggle-child-class" data-target=".target" data-toggle="hidden shown">Link
   <span class="target hidden">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
   </span>
  </a>
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.shown {
  display:block;
}
```

```
  $('.onhover-toggle-child-class').on(
    'mouseenter mouseleave',
    function() {
      var element = $(this);
      var selector = element.data('target');
      var child = element.find(selector);
      var classes = element.data('toggle');


      child.toggleClass(classes);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Similar solution is available in below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852037/show-random-image-on-hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is you should create an `array` of the image link and using  `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);` get random index from the length

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width='device-width', initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .shown {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="onhover-toggle-child-class" data-target=".target" data-toggle="hidden shown">Link
        <span class="target hidden">
            <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
        </span>
    </a>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var cars = ["https://via.placeholder.com/150", "https://via.placeholder.com/250", "https://via.placeholder.com/350","https://via.placeholder.com/450","https://via.placeholder.com/550"];

        $('.onhover-toggle-child-class').on(
            'mouseenter mouseleave',
            function () {
                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); // returns a random integer from 0 to 4
                var imageUrl = cars[random];
                $('img').attr("src", imageUrl);
                var element = $(this);
                var selector = element.data('target');
                var child = element.find(selector);
                var classes = element.data('toggle');


                child.toggleClass(classes);
            }
        );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helped 
Thanks

Comment: Please ACCEPT this answer by clicking the green tick

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var imagesArray = ["a.jpg", "b.jpg", "c.jpg", "d.jpg", "e.jpg", "f.jpg"];

    $(document).on("mouseenter", "#myImg", function(){
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
        var imgSrc= "'"+imagesArray[num]+"'";
        $(".randomImg").attr("src", imgSrc);
    });

</script>

<button id="myImg" type="button">Hover me</button>
<br><br>
<img src="default.jpg" class="randomImg" />
```

Comment: Created an array with different images names.Then generated a random number between the array index range (0 to length-1). Used this random index to set the image attribute source each time user hovers on it.