# Function wont switch out images when trying to use a random number

Tags: javascript, html, image, random

I'm working on a slot machine game where i take 3 random numbers and assign them to different images.

However, I can't get my images to display when you click the button to play the game.

I have the stock images there but when you click SPIN it should replace them with new images based on random numbers.

How can I get the new images to display?.

My code:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Slots</title>
      <link href="../style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="random.js">
        function spinslots() {
          var lemon = document.getElementById('lemon.jpg');
          var donut = document.getElementById('donut.jpg');
          var cherry = document.getElementById('cherry.jpg');
          var bar = document.getElementById('bar.jpg');

          var random_1;
              random_1= Math.floor((Math.random()*4 )+ 1);
          var random_2;
              random_2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*4 )+ 1);
          var random_3;
              random_3 = Math.floor((Math.random()*4 )+ 1);

          if (random_1 == 1) {
            document.getElementById("slot_1").src = "lemon.jpg";
          }
          if (random_1 == 2) {
            document.getElementById("slot_1").src = "donut.jpg";
          }
          if (random_1 == 3) {
            document.getElementById("slot_1").src = "cherry.jpg";
          }
          if (random_1 == 4) {
            document.getElementById("slot_1").src = "bar.jpg";
          }

          if (random_2 == 1) {
            document.getElementById("slot_2").src = "lemon.jpg";
          }
          if (random_2 == 2) {
            document.getElementById("slot_2").src = "donut.jpg";
          }
          if (random_2 == 3) {
            document.getElementById("slot_2").src = "cherry.jpg";
          }
          if (random_2 == 4) {
            document.getElementById("slot_2").src = "bar.jpg";
          }

          if (random_3 == 1) {
            document.getElementById("slot_3").src = "lemon.jpg";
          }
          if (random_3 == 2) {
            document.getElementById("slot_3").src = "donut.jpg";
          }
          if (random_3 == 3) {
            document.getElementById("slot_3").src = "cherry.jpg";
          }
          if (random_3 == 4) {
            document.getElementById("slot_3").src = "bar.jpg";
          }

          if (random_1 == random_2 == random_3) {
            alert("Congradulations, you won!");
          }
        }     
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Test your luck! Click the SPIN button</h1>
      <p><button value="Spin" onclick="spinslots();"> SPIN </button></p>
      <p>
        <div class="SlotDiv" id="div_1"><image id="slot_1" src="images/lemon.jpg"></image></div>
        <div class="SlotDiv" id="div_2"><image id="slot_2" src="images/cherry.jpg"></image></div>
        <div class="SlotDiv" id="div_3"><image id="slot_3" src="images/bar.jpg"></image></div>
      </p>

      <p>Credits: <div class="OutputBox" type="numeric" id="Credits" size="10">20</div></p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script tag has both a src attribute and content. Is this intentional? Do you get any errors on your browser console when running the code?

Comment: I was told to use it this way, now that i checked the console however it gives me these errors: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2slots.html:92 Uncaught ReferenceError: spinslots is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (slots.html:92)

Comment: i added <script type="text/javascript"> below the first script tag and it seemed to fix the second error from the console. However it still does not bring up a different image when i click SPIN so the inital problem is still there

Comment: Are you sure you have the image paths set correctly? Is it "bar.jpg" or "images/bar.jpg"?

Comment: would that go in the if statements after the src = " " ?    -   I think you where right about the images/bar.jpg as that is how the path is set, but i changed it to that and it still does not appear to be working.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can improve about the code:

- Don't use both `src` and `content` in your `<script>` tag, as [this won't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src).
- Your `getElementById` calls should use the value from the `id` attribute, not the `src`.
- You can set the initial value in the declaration line. i.e. `var random_1 = Math.floor(...`
- [Use `===` for comparing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)
- `a === b === c` should be `a === b && b === c` (thanks @jonas-h)
- You should reduce code duplication, the code has the same logic repeated multiple times.
- You should use `<img>` not `<image>` since the latter is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image)
- Since `<img>` elements have no content, you can use the short version to close them: `<img src="..." />`
- `<p>` tags cannot contain block (`div`) elements inside, use divs instead.

Example of refactored code:

```js
function spinslots() {
  const images = [
    // lemon:
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/03/15/07/lemon-25244_960_720.png',
    // donut:
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f0/Simpsons_Donut.svg/1024px-Simpsons_Donut.svg.png',
    //cherry:
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/10/23/cherries-157113_960_720.png',
    //bar:
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/04/26/20/00/jackpot-42993_960_720.png',
    ];
    const random_1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    const random_2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    const random_3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

    document.getElementById("slot_1").src = images[random_1];
    document.getElementById("slot_2").src = images[random_2];
    document.getElementById("slot_3").src = images[random_3];
   
    if (random_1 === random_2 && random_1 === random_3) {
      alert("Congratulations, you won!");
    }
  }
```

```css
.SlotDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.SlotDiv img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Slots</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Test your luck! Click the SPIN button</h1>
  <div>
    <button value="Spin" onclick="spinslots();"> SPIN </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="SlotDiv" id="div_1">
      <img id="slot_1" src="images/lemon.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="SlotDiv" id="div_2">
      <img id="slot_2" src="images/cherry.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="SlotDiv" id="div_3">
      <img id="slot_3" src="images/bar.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Credits: <span class="OutputBox" type="numeric" id="Credits" size="10">20</span></p>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Further enhancements:

- note that the alert shows before the images change, due to it being executed synchronously. You can delay the message for a better effect.
- the images take some time to show in the initial load, you can [preload the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/javascript-preloading-images) to avoid this.

Comment: you're welcome - I kept playing and I couldn't win, sooo frustrating ;-)

Comment: thanks for the help! turns out the entire problem with the code was the script tag, I know its a little longer than what you did but it seems to work fine now, thanks for all the great tips and your help.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. If this post answered your question you should consider up-voting or accepting the answer, or even posting your own answer and accepting that one!