# Images Failing to Preload - Causing TypeErrors

Tags: javascript

I'm making a vanilla JS flappy bird game, but I'm getting a `TypeError: Can't read property 'x' of undefined.` for a pipeTop variable.

While the background image loads, I'm guessing the pipe image doesn't load before pipeTop[i].x is called.

I tried pre-loading all of the images, as well as include a `window.onload` for my `draw` function, but it doesn't seem to serve the images (or their properties) before the logic is implemented.

```
// draw images

window.onload = function draw() {

    ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0);

    for (var i = 0; i < pipe.length; i++){
        ctx.drawImage(pipeTop, pipe[i].x, pipe[i].y);
        ctx.drawImage(pipeBottom, pipe[i].x, pipe[i].y+constant);

        pipe[i].x--;

        if (pipe[i].x == 125){
            pipe.push({
                x : cvs.width,
                y : Math.floor(Math.random()*pipeTop.height)-pipeTop.height
            });
        }
    }

    // Detect Collision

    if (bX + bird.width >= pipe[i].x && bX <= pipe[i].x + pipeTop.width && (bY <= pipe[i].y + pipeTop.height || bY+bird.height >= pipe[i].y+constant || bY + bird.height >= cvs.height - fg.height)){
        location.reload();
    }

    if (pipe[i].x == 5) {
        score+= 5;
        score.play();
    }
```

Pre-loading I tried (now commented out) was:

```
// function preloadImage(url) {
//     var img = new Image();
//     img.src = url;
// }

// preloadImage(
//     "images/pipeBottom.png",
//     "images/pipeTop.png",
//     "images/fg.png",
//     "images/bg.png",
//     "images/bird.png"
// )
```

The line that has the typeError is:

```
    if (bX + bird.width >= pipe[i].x && bX <= pipe[i].x + pipeTop.width && (bY <= pipe[i].y + pipeTop.height || bY+bird.height >= pipe[i].y+constant || bY + bird.height >= cvs.height - fg.height)){....
```

Essentially, I'm trying to load the images before any game logic runs so that I avoid these Undefined and Type errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you define `pipeTop`, `score`, `ctx` and `pipe`?

Comment: You need to add a load event handler, and then do any further processing for the specific image in there. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38204934/10955263 If you want to process multiple images in one go when they all have finished loading, then you need to keep a counter and only have the callback actually start doing stuff, when that has reached the total number of images. (Or uses promises, if you want to write “modern” JavaScript.)

Comment: @Justinas ctx is on line 4 of my code then the other variables are after the images are defined

Comment: @04FS Thanks, though now I'm getting `reference error: pipeTop is not defined` followed by the console.log for `Number of images loaded`, followed by `TypeError: allImagesLoadedCallback is not a function`