# Prevent javascript lightbox to rezises the src to the data-src before it's displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little annoying bug in my custom written Lightbox. When the user presses an image to view it on my website, I have a .gif that is 256x256px that is shown until my actual image has loaded. However, just before the  when the data-src (the actual image I want to load) shows, the .gif briefly for a split second resizes to full image size. I wish to not have the gif resizing to the full size of the data-src image.

Here is an image of the issue:
[image]

I believe that I need to modify some of the code, either in the javascript section or the css.

The html code for the actual image that gets opened (*The slides class is part of the javascript that determines which image to show in the lightbox*):

```html
<img class="slides" src="img/global/lazyload/lazyload.gif" data-src="img/home/Material_1.png">
```

Here is the CSS code (The `<img class"slides" src="...` is inside the a div with `id=lightbox`):

```css
/* Lightbox Main Window */
#lightbox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Lightbox Slides (Image Styling) */
.slides {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Here is the code for when the lightbox loads in the image:

```
// Show Slides
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";}
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        slides[slideIndex-1].setAttribute("src",slides[slideIndex-1].getAttribute("data-src"));
}
```

I tried to switch the position of `slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";` and `slides[slideIndex-1].setAttribute("src",slides[slideIndex-1].getAttribute("data-src"));` but it didn't change the outcome.

Any help regarding my issue will be appreciated.

Comment: First load the image, and only if it is loaded/available, change the visibility and source.

Comment: @Andreas that is the perfect plan. However, I can't find any information on how I would load my data-src (dataset) with JavaScript. Is it even possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript