# Is it possible to run an event before set / get attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` to display a higher resolution image. The src stores the low resolution image and data-src stores the high resolution image.

**The HTML code would look something like this:**

```html
<img class="image" src="img/lowres.png" data-src="img/highres.png">
```

**The javascript code would look something like this:**

```
image.setAttribute("src",image.getAttribute("data-src"));
```

Do I have any access to run any code before the src changes into the data-src? For example fade out the src image and fade in the data-src image?

*The code is executed on a button press.*

Comment: You could monkeypatch HTMLElement.setAttribute to intercept the call, but that's a *really* weird thing to do

Comment: Interesting, is there a better way to go about this? I really wish to keep the ability to manually change the src and data-src.

Comment: I think you can do it by changing the class name with another which include an animation

Comment: @CertainPerformance

The reason for asking is because I have a rather weird resizing issue with my lightbox. Previous post that goes into why I am asking this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930241/prevent-javascript-lightbox-to-rezises-the-src-to-the-data-src-before-its-displ

Comment: @matrixersp the idea with adding a new class is great. However, how would I run the new class as soon as the data-src is ready to show?

Comment: Instead of starting a new question to find some workaround you might want to add a [mcve] to your other question and get the source of the problem fixed.