# Download background-images of divs before using those divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am doing an animation where based on the scroll I change multiple background images of a main div `amoled-section`. Hence, I am doing this by adding a class whenever the scroll hits a trigger e.g. `#amoled-section-frame6`.Every time when trigger hits`#amoled-section-frame6` it adds a class to  `amoled-section.on-frame6`

```
.amoled-section.on-frame-6 {
  background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/portrait-cheerful-male-architect-wearing-260nw-1060056851.jpg");
  z-index: 1;
}
```

It was working all good until I observed that if I have a multiple image change it will require a time to download the image and will create a glitch effect. The problem that I  want to resolve is somehow download background-images of divs before using them and in this way, the background image transition will work fine.

I attached in Codepen a link to the full code, however is not working probably because Srollmagic is not that flexible with Codepen. Link below.

https://codepen.io/obsesie/pen/qBZKzGz

Comment: You need to look at preloading of images based on ajax or by counting the scrollup r down event. Here https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/#:~:text=JavaScript%20Method%20%232&text=As%20you%20can%20see%2C%20each,as%20many%20images%20as%20necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preloading images with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript)

Comment: You can preload images using CSS only, instead of using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with ScrollMagic.js before and had an issue as same as you have. There are two solutions I prefer.

1. Embed images with the style of "display: none"
2. Use javascript to preload those images.

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
            var images = new Array()
            function preload() {
                for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                    images[i] = new Image()
                    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
                }
            }
            preload(
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
                "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
            )
        //--><!]]>
    </script>
   ```

There would be other solutions but I hope this would help.
Also, this link would be useful for you.
[https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/#:~:text=JavaScript%20Method%20%232&text=As%20you%20can%20see%2C%20each,as%20many%20images%20as%20necessary](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20Method%20%232&text=As%20you%20can%20see%2C%20each,as%20many%20images%20as%20necessary).

Comment: If the images are not used for a while the browser cleans cache and those images have to be refetched.