# Preloading image not working in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to preload an image in `useEffect`, but it doesn't seem to be downloading the image when app component mounts.

I'm doing something like the following:

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src =
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601758065893-25c11bfa69b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1279&q=80";

    setTimeout(() => setShow(true), 10000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {show && (<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601758065893-25c11bfa69b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1279&q=80 />)}
    </>
  )
```

The idea here is to download the image ahead of time, so that way when the `img` is to be displayed, it wouldn't have to download the media.

Unfortunately, `useEffect` doesn't seem to be triggering the image download. Why doesn't it fetch the image when the component mounts?

[image: cool-grass-2x1ob]

Comment: What are you trying to say not clear

Comment: I'm trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript). Preload/lazy load image, so it is ready, when a component needs to use it. Because right now, the image is downloaded only when `show  === true`, and the `<img />` is in the DOM.

Comment: why do you preload an image and then shows another image show the one you preloaded

Comment: Type in question, made the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a component called `Image`, so when you call `new Image()` you're calling a new instance of the component rendering the native `Image` constructor useless. So you'll have to build your image by using the `createElement` function on the `document` object.

Then instead of a `setTimeout` listen for the `load` event to change the `show` state the moment the image finished loading.

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "./Image";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src =
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601758065893-25c11bfa69b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1279&q=80";
    image.onload = () => {
      setShow(true);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">{show && <Image />}</div>;
}
```