# How to get the image preload in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, preload

I have a preload link in my html. 
`<link rel="preload" href="sprite.png" id="mySprite" as="image">`
How can I convert this to a `Image` in Javascript? 
(`let sprite = new Image(myPreloadeImageFromHTML)`

I have a lot of images needed, but they do not load on time, which results in no images shown.
How can I preload it and obtain it in Javscript as an `Image` using a `<link rel="preload">`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preloading images with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript)

Comment: But how do I use that `<link>` tag to render the image in my canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a link and a canvas in HTML and using javascript I am fetching that link href then created an image from that link and then inserted that image into the canvas.

HTML:

```
<!-- Your Link -->
<link rel="preload" href="https://www.android-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/demo_image.jpg" id="mySprite" as="image">

<!-- Create Canvas -->
<canvas id="my-canvas" />
```

JS:

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = document.getElementById("mySprite").href;

var c = document.getElementById("my-canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

img1.onload = function () {
  c.width = img1.width;
  c.height = img1.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
}
```

Here is the reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/uLwpsdqt/

Comment: But I don't want to reload it... I would like to have the preloaded image directly acessible by javscript...