# Angular preloading images best practice

Tags: angular

Any ideal about preloading images in Angular with best practice.
With 'Slow Internet Connection' When I load my component I see all texts and only after 2 sec I see my images.
How can I improve this user experience ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are many techniques for optimizing FCP/LCP, you can read about some and the new NgOptimizedImage - new v14.2 feature: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/angular-image-directive/

Also general advice on lazy loading, which is probably smarter than preloading: https://web.dev/lazy-loading-images/ (not Angular specific)

If you really need to preload, check out this thread: [Preloading images with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript)