# How could JavaScript possibly *pre*-load an image if the <script> is already loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, preload

Looking at this [question about preloading images with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75521344/preload-the-images-in-head-using-jquery), I assumed it was a misunderstanding about client vs server js rendering. However, it was closed as a dupe of [another highly voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript) about preloading images with js.

My understanding is that by the time the `<script>`s are executing (late in the page render, as per: [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)), that any benefit to preloading images are nullified, since you are already past the load stage, so you aren't *pre*-loading, but simply loading.

What benefits are expected by *pre*-loading via js?
Is it conceptually possible that images loaded via js are in an way *pre*-loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it conceptually possible that images loaded via js are in an way pre-loaded?

My current understanding is that the images are loaded before they're displayed on the page e.g. images in a gallery that the user has to open.

> What benefits are expected by pre-loading via js?

More responsive sites.