# Images shown on the page only after scrolling to them

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, loading

I'm just finishing up the game page. Similar to mobile "subway surfers". I noticed, however, that when you first enter the site and start the game, the obstacle (picture showing the obstacle) appears only when you are right next to it (which is much too late to react)(Images load too slow). So to solve this problem:

1. Images should be downloaded even if they have not yet been displayed.

- or...

2. They should be displayed off the screen before starting the game to have the effect of loading as in the first point.

You can experience this error by visiting my site. The source code is visible so you can review it.

link: http://ds_autogame.ct8.pl/

Additional auxiliary photo:

[Screenshot of the game Car Surfer!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4QTM.jpg)

The garbage next to the car appeared only at the height of the hood (the image was loaded at the moment when the hitbox was at the height of the hood. Because of this, sometimes you can hit an invisible obstacle ＞﹏＜ )

I want to find out if there is e. g. a meta tag that informs the browser that it should first download all the content of the page then only display it (or download images first).
If in any way you can not force the way to load the page I will probably reiterate through all the photos from the page somewhere off the screen (so that they are displayed).

I tried to use the features from the suggested article: [Preloading images with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript)
but unfortunately mistakes pop up.

[Image with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db3LZ.png)

```
function preloadImage(url){
const img = new Image();
img.src = url;
return img
}
function preloadImages() {
const images = []
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  images[i] = preloadImage(arguments[i])
}
return images
}
const images = preloadImages
("Grafika/terrain_default1",
"Grafika/terrain_default2",
"Grafika/thrashes_1",
"Grafika/thrashes_2",
"Grafika/tree_1",
"Grafika/tree_2",
"Grafika/tree_3")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preloading images with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @imvain2 That's right, the title of the article is correct. However, many of the answers are from 2016 and may be outdated. in my opinion they answer the problem in a slightly too complicated way. (I'm a beginner and I'm sorry that I probably duplicate the question. However, I need something like "individual help" heh)

Comment: @DominikSzkotland in your edit the code that you include doesn't include any file extensions like .png, .jpg etc

Comment: you're right. how could this happen ;(. I think it'll work now. By the way, was there any other way to control this phenomenon? (order of downloading items on the page?)