# How can i make random img background function load faster?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, web-frontend

I'm beginner at coding and thats almost my first wesbite to test it i added random background option but it got problem in first load for every background img it take ages that ruin the view because there is overlay div above it so when it changes sometimes it takes time to load so it only shows the overlay which make  it look laggy
https://special-project-demo.netlify.app/
this is the website to test it and see what i mean when turn on random background option from the side
and this the js code

```
let backgroundArray = ["Background-1.jpg" , "Background-2.jpg" ,"Background-4.jpg" , "Background-5.jpg"]
let isRandom = false; 
let randomInterval;
function randomBackground() {
  if (isRandom === true){
    randomInterval = setInterval(() => {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * backgroundArray.length)
      landing.style.backgroundImage = 'url("imgs/'+backgroundArray[random]+'")'
     } ,7000)
  } else {
    clearInterval(randomInterval)
  }
}
randomBackground()
```

thats the part control the background

i even set transision 3s for the div  and increase the setinterval  time and lower the img quailty but it still the same

Comment: you could preload the images

Comment: Look into preloading your images.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript

Comment: Another thing to try is optimising your images for file size. Using an optimal format like [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp), reducing quality, reducing resolution, etc will all help to make your images load faster