# What is the corect way to preload images in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, jsx, preload

I have a Gallery component in React. I have 40 image URLs and by default, I only show 10, by mapping 10 URLs (in `items` I always put the exact amount of "images" that need to be rendered):

```
   {items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <img
            key={index}
            src={item.src}
            alt={item.alt}
          />
         );
   })}
```

My question is, how do I preload 4 more images (that are only going to be shown if clicked on "show more")?

I found this very helpful [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript) that seems to tackle this very issue. So in my current implementation, I have something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10 + numberOfExtraPrelodedImages; i++) {
  const item = galeryItems[imageLoadedAndCount.count + i];
  if (item?.url) {
    new Image().src = item.url;
  }
}
```

My only concern is that now when in the `img` tag I "recall" the URL doesn't that send a now API request to "get the latest content"? Or does it use the preloaded content from the code shown above? Is this the correct way to preload images in React?

Comment: It shouldn't, as long as cache is enabled and correct cache headers are set on image.

Comment: How does one set them headers correctly?

Comment: A correctly setup back end you shouldn't really need to worry about it, generally a back end that ships static assets will at the very least implement eTag.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag  But you can go a bit deeper here and avoid the pre-flight requests by manipulating cache headers ->  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control  But be careful here, as it's easy to get that bit wrong.

Comment: Thank you! So if the headers are set up correctly, it won't work the same as a regular fetch?

Comment: Also even using eTag,  you can mix with `max-age`, that will help prevent pre-flight requests, but obviously this doesn't want to be too large or it negates the benefits of eTag.  To find out what the browser is doing, check out the network tab in your developer tools, what your after is the requests saying memory cache / disk cache under the size column, if you have this then the second `fetch` has not done the request to server again.

Comment: When you say won't work the same, do you mean in doing the physical requests to the server, then yes, the second request won't be doing this but getting the data locally from cache, but in all other regards it will work the same..