# jquery change image on mouse rollover

Tags: jquery, html, rollover

I have been having problems with this. I think this should be pretty simple but I cannot seem to get it to work. I want a new image to appear when rolling over my facebook button. Thanks for your help!

```
    <p align="right">
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/AerialistPress" ><img height="30px" id="facebook" class="changePad" alt="Aerialist Press Facebook Page" src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/facebook300.jpg" /></a> 
           <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/AerialistPress" > <img height="30px" class="changePad" alt="Aerialist Press Twitter Page" src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/twitter300.jpg" /></a>
           <a href="http://www.pinterest.com/aerialistpress" ><img height="30px" class="changePad" alt="Aerialist Press Pinterest Page" src="/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/pinterest300.jpg" /></a>
</p>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('#facebook').mouseover(function() { jQuery('#facebook').attr('src').replace('/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/facebook-roll.jpg'); })

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attr` method returns the value of the property specified (in this case, 'src'), and the `replace` is trying to modify the string and return a new instance. However, you're not doing anything with the new instance.

To set the attribute you must pass an additional parameter to the `attr` method.

Here's the documentation for the `attr` method:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Your code should be:

```
jQuery('#facebook').attr('src', '/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/facebook-roll.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `replace`, just set the `src` attr directly:

```
jQuery('#facebook').attr('src', '/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/facebook-roll.jpg');
```

Comment: Thanks! it changes but then when i move the mouse out it stays the same. Is there a way to get it to change back on mouse out?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
jQuery('#facebook').attr('src').replace('/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/facebook-roll.jpg');
```

to

```
jQuery('#facebook').attr('src', '/sites/aerialist.localhost/files/images/facebook-roll.jpg');
```

You can also use `$('#facebook')` instead of `$('#facebook')`

Comment: Thanks! it changes but then when i move the mouse out it stays the same. Is there a way to get it to change back on mouse out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589382/jquery-changing-the-src-of-another-image-on-rollover

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go!

```
$("#img").hover(function(){
//mouseover
     $(this).attr('src', 'https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/profile_images/1768071248/smile_normal.jpg'); 
    },
    function(){
//mouseout
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.bestfreeicons.com/smimages/Emotes-face-smile-icon.png');
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<script type ="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#facebook').mouseenter(function() { 
     $('#facebook').attr("src","heretheotherimage.png"); 
 })

 $('#facebook').mouseleave(function() { 
     $('#facebook').attr("src","heretheimage.png"); 
 })

 });
 </script>

 <img src ="heretheimage.png" id ="facebook" />
```