# Swap back image on hover out with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<a href="#"><img class="swap" src="/Static/Images/Meny_normal_01.png"  alt="" /></a>
```

and this is my Jquery code and what it does is that when I hover over my img it swaps to another img, but I would like to have a hover out and then it swap back to the old img.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.swap').hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '/Static/Images/Meny_hover_01.png');
    });
});
```

Would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: People who took the time to help you might appreciate you marking an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) binds two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and when you leaves the elements.

```
$(".swap").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).attr('src', '/Static/Images/Meny_hover_01.png');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).attr('src', '/Static/Images/Meny_normal_01.png');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass 2 handlers into the hover  - like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.swap').hover(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '/Static/Images/Meny_hover_01.png');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).attr('src', '/Static/Images/Meny_normal_01.png');
    }
    );
});
```

Have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ for more info

Or a similar item on SO: [jquery change image on mouse rollover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058912/jquery-change-image-on-mouse-rollover)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".swap").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", function(i, val) {
        return val.indexOf("hover") == -1
          ? val.replace("normal", "hover")
          : val.replace("hover", "normal");
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UJR8M/