# How to prevent Jquery mouseover event from executing on moving mouse on transperent image area?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I have used code described on below mentioned SO answer 
[Change the image source on rollover using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery/540355#540355)
to change image on mouse over.

```
$(function() {
    $("img")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "over.gif";
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("over", "");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    });
});
```

Problem I am facing is that, my images are in png format which have some transparent areas. That means I have non- rectangular shaped images in my website.

Above JQuery changes image src even when mouse is over on transparent area.

Can someone please suggest some way so that image change occurs only when mouse is hover on visible image area?

Comment: With simple Javascript/jQuery, you don't have access to the image data. You can't decide whether a part of it is visible or not. Maybe an old school image map could be a solution for you.

Comment: I am ok with any solution using some div/table surrounding the image

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Not sure is imagemap supported by all browsers ?

Comment: It's so ancient, that everything supports it :). And it also made it into HTML5.

Comment: here a quick demo with jQuery and map http://jsfiddle.net/at7g8/

Comment: Using image map seems to be a good solution. I will give it a try.
Thanks bazmegakapa & Sotiris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `map` html property for this http://jsfiddle.net/u9cYZ/3/

or

you can use `css3 mask` property check this

http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

http://girliemac.com/blog/2010/09/20/201/