# Javascript loading an image on hover over a link

Tags: javascript

i am new to java script and i am designing my web site but i want to load a new image on a particular place of my web page when a user hover over the home,here is the code.

```
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <img src="yourImage.jpg" alt="Home" id="image1" onmouseover="image1.src='home.jpg';" onmouseout="image1.src='myImage.jpg';" /> <br />
        <a href="#" onmouseover=image1.src='home.jpg';" onmouseout="image1.src='yourImage.jpg';">Hoover Me!</a>
        </body>
        </html>
```

This code is not working.Please Help me to find out the error in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not refer to the img as `image1.src` first you have to assign `image1=document.getElementById('image1')` then you can refer it as `image1.src`. There is also a much simpler method to do that. You can also refer to the current image or object as `this.src` in JavaScript. See the corrected code with changes bellow:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="yourImage.jpg" alt="[ Home ]" id="image1" onmouseover="this.src='home.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='myImage.jpg';" /><br />
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('image1').src='home.jpg';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('image1').src='yourImage.jpg';">Hoover Me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the method `document.getElementById()` to get the image object before try to manipulate it:

```
<body>
    <img src="yourImage.jpg" alt="Home" id="image1" onmouseover="document.getElementById('image1').src='home.jpg';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('image1').src='myImage.jpg';" /> <br />
    <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('image1').src='home.jpg';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('image1').src='yourImage.jpg';">Hoover Me!</a>
</body>
```

You should consider using JQuery to do this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

- `image1` doesn't have any meaning.  You will need to use
  `document.getElementById('image1').src` instead of just `image1.src`.
- You're missing the starting quote for the `onmouseover` attribute of
  the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not using document.getElementById, you'll also encounter a lag on mouse over, unless the image has been pre-loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To access the img element from it's own inline attributes, you need to use the 'this' keyword:

```
<img src="yourImage.jpg" alt="Home" id="image1" onmouseover="this.src='yourOtherImage.jpg';" />
```

Rather than do it inline, you could also use a javascript library, like jQuery, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery), which would give you more flexibility if you want to do more later e.g. add animations, but that's up to you and how much of a challenge you feel like :)