# Change jQuery image src dynamically

Tags: jquery, dynamic, slideshow, jquery-backstretch

I saw just wondering how it would be possible to change a src every say 5 seconds,

I am using

```
$.backstretch("site.com/images/home5.jpg");
```

Is it possible to swap 'home5.jpg' with other image (say home6.jpg and home7.jpg) like a slideshow? I'm not sure how to change it dynamically

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to change it every 5 seconds you'd need to use `setInterval()`:

```
var loop = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    var imgNumber = loop % 5; // assuming there are 5 images.
    $.backstretch("site.com/images/home" + imgNumber + ".jpg");
    loop++;
}, 5000);
```

**UPDATE**

After reading the documentation it appear this functionality is built into the plugin already:

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Choose 'Using backstretch in a slideshow' for the code.

Comment: Hey, this works perfectly! One thing I forgot to ask is if I wanted them to fade in/out rather then a sudden change?

Comment: That depends on the plugin you're using. I'd imagine it would involve having to amend the source.

Comment: Ticked :)

I dont think it would be the plugin, as that only stretched the image (sorry forgot to mention that) I presume I set it within the setInterval? Tho I am not sure where I'd lot it in

Comment: See my update, the documentation has an example of how to create a slideshow with a fadeIn effect.

Comment: Wow, 1000 thank you's for the help, it's working exactly how I wanted it to, and 1000 apologies for not checking the pluin myself when I should have :)

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the JavaScript function `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the html of the object you've selected with .html().

$(#thing).html(" < img src='mypic.jpg' / >");

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) or a similar function to periodically change the image. To actually swap images, you can  just call `backstretch` again. From the [project page](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch):

> **Version 1.2**
>
> You can now called backstretch twice, and it will replace the existing image.

So for example:

```
$.backstretch("site.com/images/home6.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

> function slideSwitch() {
>
> ```
> var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');
>
> $active.src = //change src here (you can use array with src-s)// }
> ```
>
> $(function() {
>       setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 ); });

Comment: Eeeck.  Don't use a string with setInterval.  Pass the straight function reference.