# Loading image with jquery: Additional request in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have such a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#links a").mouseover(function () {
            $("#flag").attr("src", "/Images/" + $(this).attr("id") + ".png");
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <img id="flag" src="/Images/austria.png" alt="austria" />
</div>
<div id="links">
    <a id="austria" href="#">austria</a>
    <a id="brazil" href="#">brazil</a> 
    <a id="japan" href="#">japan</a>
</div>
```

Every thing work fine in different browser(FF10,Chrome,IE9). But when I monitor network in IE9 with "F12 developer tools", every time that mouse goes over a link, there is a aditional request for image. But in FF and Chrome, by checking with FireBug and Developer tools, for each image, there is just one requst and second time you go over a link, there is no request.

- what is the problem with IE9 (or my code ;))?
- Is there any other solutions for my problem to prevent from this problem?

(Actually I want something like Yahoo Hot news, that for every news image, its request just called once, even in IE9).

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if you have already loaded the current image; therefore, it will reload it even though it is already there. Some of the browsers were probably using a cached version of the image and therefore did not go get it again.

```
$(function () {
    $("#links a").mouseover(function () {
        var $flag = $("#flag");
        var newImage = "/Images/" + $(this).attr("id") + ".png";

        if ($flag.attr("src").indexOf(newImage) == -1)
            $flag.attr("src", newImage);
    });
});
```

**Edit**:

From our conversation I wrote up the following, is it what you were referring too?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="flag">
    <img id="flag" src="/Images/austria.png" alt="austria" />
</div>
<div id="links">
    <a id="austria" href="#">austria</a>
    <a id="brazil" href="#">brazil</a> 
    <a id="japan" href="#">japan</a>
</div>​​​
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(function () {
    $("#links a").mouseover(function () {
        var $flag = $(".flag");;
        var $flagImg = $("#flag");
        var imageID = $(this).attr("id");

        if ($flagImg.attr("src").indexOf(imageID) == -1)
            $flag.html('<img id="flag" src="/Images/' + imageID  + '.png" alt="' + imageID + '" />');
    });
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nSE8B/7/)

Comment: it must be == instead of != in if statement ;)

Comment: I was too hurry to accept the answer.The problem is still there.It still send request when I go over Japan link and again back to Austria flag (in IE) with this solution and it is completely logical. Your solution just prevent from additional request when you go over Japan flag and again Japan flag. But in my code and yours, there is not such a problem even in IE9.(if your go over single link many times there is no additional request)

Comment: I think you are at the mercy of the browser caching the image. I dont believe there is anything you can do to prevent it from loading every time if you are wanting to switch the images in and out. If you really do not want it to get the image several times, you could have more than one image and switch which one is showing, but this obviously is not ideal.

Comment: OK. Maybe it is IE bug. But is there any other solution to solve this problem? (Of course there is. Yahoo hot news do this and it work with IE fine without any additional request) So I must find the solution. ;D

Comment: it seems that Yahoo completely change the div tag that contains news image and body of news

Comment: That is interesting, never really thought about trying that. Did you give it a try?

Comment: Do you mean fill it with new content or swap it out for another?