# Imagebutton JS swap dosen´t work on webkit/phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, image, cordova, webkit

I´am trying to get an simple imagebutton to work in Phonegap. I wanna swap image when clicked and forward to location after a short time.

So what i have tried:

```
function highl(Bildname,BildURL,Link) {
document.images[Bildname].src = BildURL;
window.setTimeout(forward,1000);

function forward() {
window.location = Link;
}
}
```

in HTML just links like:

```
<a href="javascript:highl('level01','level1h.png','test.html')"><img name="level01" src="level1.png" border="0"></a>
```

Works well in my Moz, but not in Webkit/phonegap (swap doesen´t work forward is well).

Can anybody help?

edit: also doesen´t work in chrome...

Comment: I am not really surprised that a mobile browser doesn't listen to changes on `src`. Even desktop browser may have difficulties with that (I remember Chrome had a memory leak, for instance)

Comment: Webkit doesn't support DOM attribute mutation (see [issue 8191](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8191)) marked **won't fix**.
I don't know if there is a relation with your question

Comment: Maybe there are any suggestions to solve this on an other way?

Comment: btw. i try to stay away from drawing all with canvas because of the calculation for every resolution....

Answer (score 0):

Webkit doesn't support DOM attribute mutation (see [issue 8191](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8191)) marked **won't fix**.
There might be a link with your issue.

As a workaround, I think you should simply remove the content of the DOM node, and create a new image node instead.

**Edit**: with code

You need to identify the container.
Also, I set href, so that I javascrpt is disabled, the link can still be followed.
If javascript is enabled, `return false` tells the browser not to follow the link.

```
<a href="test.html" onClick="return highl(this, 'level1h.png', 'test.html');">
```

javascript. I have inlined `forward` because it was very short, but you don't need to.

```
function highl(el, imgURL, link) {
  var img =  new Image();
  img.src = imgUrl;
  // remove current image. TODO ensure firstChild is not null?
  el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
  // place new image
  el.append(img);
  setTimeout(function() {window.location=link;}, 1000);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: i´m pretty new to all this stuff. so i have read alot about DOM today but can´t find an other solution. Can you give me a litle snippet to help me on the Way?

Comment: This also dosent work for me in Webkit. Now i used jquery to swap buttons. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery) Anyway Thank you for help!