# jQuery on click add to src of image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say for example I have two images called:-

```
<img alt="img-estate" src="images/estate.png" />

<img alt="img-saloon" src="images/saloon.png" />
```

On click of either of these images I want to be able to change the src to add `-active` on click.

So if I click on #img-estate the image src should be `images/estate-active.png`. So basically it reads the original src location and just adds `-active` on click.

How would I go about doing this using jQuery?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery

Comment: $("img").click(function() { $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.png','-active.png') ) });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will, following a click, effectively *toggle* the `-active` string:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var src = this.src;
    this.src = src.indexOf('-active') == -1 ? src.replace('.png','-active.png') : src.replace('-active.png','.png');
});
```

If you'd rather just *add* that string:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    var src = this.src;
    this.src = src.replace('.png','-active.png');
});
```

To apply this to only those elements listed in the question, you could amend the selector to:

```
$('img[alt^="img-"]')
```

Which selects only those images whose `alt` attribute starts with the string `img-`.

Incidentally, if you'd prefer to use the jQuery `attr()` method, you don't have to call the same method twice to do so, simply use an anonymous function instead:

```
$('img[alt^="img-"]').attr('src', function(index, currentSrc){
    return currentSrc.replace('.png', '-active.png');
});
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [attribute-starts-with (`[attribute^="value"]`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.attr('src', $this.attr('src').replace(/\.png$/, '-active.png'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('img').click(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   src = src.substring(0, src.length-4);
   $(this).attr('src', src+'-active.png');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ssomething like this might do the trick

```
$('img').on('click', function() {
   var $img = $(this);
   var currentSrc = $img.prop('src');
   $img.prop('src', currentSrc.replace('.png','-active.png'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GTfcG/)

Answer (score 0):

This function should work perfectly:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.png/, '-active.png'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add a class to the image:

```
<img alt="img-estate" class="clickable_image" src="images/estate.png" />

$('.clickable_image).on('click, function(e){

      var source = $(e.target).attr('src').Split('.');
      $(e.target).attr('src','source[0] + '-active' + source[1]);



});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
 $('img').click(function(){
 var image =  $(this).attr('src');
 alert(image);
 var newimage = image.replace('.png','-active.png');
 alert(newimage);

 $(this).attr('src',"newimage");
 return false;
 });
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/2UptD/)