# Simple Change an image in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, swap

I have a jquery script that sets a few options on page load.

However I want to set the image in a sitemap with id #User_Menu_Options_TreeView1t8

How do i achieve this ? ( as I have searched this site and not found exactly what am looking for )

many thanks

E

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Set the image in a sitemap? If you want to change the background image of an item based on the ID, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#User_Menu_Options_TreeView1t8").css("background", "url:('myimagelocation.png')");
});
```

If I misunderstood, and you already have an image on the page but you want to change the source, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#User_Menu_Options_TreeView1t8").attr("src", "myimagelocation.png");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Get the image and set its src with the data

```
$(function () {
    var myUrl = "/Content/Images/" + $('#MyId').val();
    $('#myImage').attr('src', myUrl);
});
```