# When clicked, toggle image and also Value in MySQL DB

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I want to create a simple way to bookmark pages in my PHP app using Javascript.

I have a list of items and each one will have an image (maybe an empty star) which when clicked, will toggle a value in MySQL field for that specific user, (from 0 to 1) and also change the image for that item in the list to bookmarked (likely a full yellow star)

Where do I start?

Comment: A good starting point would have been http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: More seriously (?) that question is too broad to expect a decent answer, I think. Maybe you should at least try to show us what you have done so far and/or some elements of the context of your application. Or your basic DB structure. Or at a bare minimum what possible solutions you might have in mind or found on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick primer:

you'll need to use javascript to trigger an action when the star is clicked. I suggest you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

The action you trigger to do the following:

- call the server to tell it the image has been clicked, with the jQuery.ajax() function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- read the response of the server to make sure the user's preference was recorded (I suggest you use JSON to encode the response from the server, easier to use in JavaScript).
- change the image.  You can read this: [Change the image source on rollover using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Happy coding