# Jquery onmouseover change image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, onmouseover

**It´s possible do this , i want change image onmouseover :**

```
<img src="icon_rss.png" border="0" alt="" onmouseover="jQuery(this).css('background-image':'url(icon_rss_over.png)');" />
```

I try change image onmouseover with jquery or i do something bad , i think i do all ok but no get results ok for change the image when go to the cursor over

---

At the moment i can´t do works fine , thank´s for the help

The best regards !!!

Answer (score 1):

You have Typo

```
onmouseover="jQuery(this).css('background-image','url(icon_rss_over.png)');"
                                                ^ //you need , not :
```

---

or you can do it also with `:` we use `.css({})` to assign multiple properties.one or more than one.

```
onmouseover="jQuery(this).css({'background-image':'url(icon_rss_over.png)'});"
                              ^                  ^                        ^
```

---

Reference

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: Continue no change me <img src="icon_rss.png" border="0" alt="" onmouseover="jQuery(this).css({'background-image':'url(icon_rss_over.png)'});" Onmouseout="" />

Answer (score 0):

You should check for duplicate threads before you post the same question. I believe this is a good enough explanation how to accomplish what you are asking for;

[Change the image source on rollover using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery)