# Changing image with jQuery based upon hasClass

Tags: jquery, replace, onclicklistener

I am piggy-backing off of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery), and would like to use this technique within an event handler that looks for a 'has class'.

The goal is to have this in a menu bar with icons/images.

So far, I am not able to find the bug in the following code:

```
$('.className').click(function(){
    $('.className').removeClass('activeDesignation');
    $(this).addClass('activeDesignation');
    if ( $('.className').hasClass('activeDesignation')){
            $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "[suffix].png");
    };
});
```

The general Syntax appears to be ok, since the following works:

```
$('.className').click(function(){
    $('.className').removeClass('activeDesignation');
    $(this).addClass('activeDesignation');
    if ( $('.className').hasClass('activeDesignation')){
            $(this).hide('slow');
    };
});
```

Just at a loss here

Comment: you are removing class at start and down you are checking if class exists. it is unclear

Comment: Logically speaking, your code is removing all 'activedesignation' then, placing it on the current 'className' that was clicked. Therefore there is no need for the `if` in the code. I see a logic fallacy; hence failing to determine what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: wow... tough room, a minus 2 for this question?  Rough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want whichever image you click on to use a different image (one with a suffix) and to have some class added to it. It looks like you want something like this:

JS (jQuery):

```
$('.item').on('click', function() {
    $('.item').removeClass('active').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('[suffix].jpg','.jpg'));
    });
    $(this).addClass('active').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg','[suffix].jpg'));
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/d3sutyac/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "[suffix].png");
```

This will successfully replace the string with the value that you want you never reassign it back to the source of the image.

```
$(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "[suffix].png"));
```

As the two comments in the question point out the if check is rather pointless

```
$('.className').click(function(){
    $('.className').removeClass('activeDesignation');
    $(this).addClass('activeDesignation')
           .attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "[suffix].png"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing `activeDesignation` from all `className` elements and then checking `$('.className').hasClass('activeDesignation')` condition which will be false always.

You can remove if condition and simply replace image extension. But you need to store this replace and then assign it again.

```
$('.className').click(function(){
    $('.className').removeClass('activeDesignation');
    $(this).addClass('activeDesignation');
    //if ( $('.className').hasClass('activeDesignation')){ // remove if 
        var newSRC = $(this).attr("src").replace(".png", "[suffix].png");//store new src
       $(this).attr("src",newSRC );
    //};
});
```