# Concatenate strings to form url

Tags: url, concatenation

I have a url that I want to use in an iframe.  The first part of the URL stays the same, the second varies by page.  So I want to concatenate them together and use the resulting variable in the src statement.  So far I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var str1="http://bitz.bz/mapplacencia";
var str2="#17/16.51876129/-88.36937785";
var str3=str1+str2;
document.write(str3);
 </script>

<p <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://hostbelize.com/hotmobile/general/mobile-legend.png" alt="" width="80% alt=" /></p>
<p <iframe width='80%' height='500px' frameBorder='0' src=str3"></iframe></p>

</body>
</html>
```

The concatenation is working as I can see it from the document.write statement.  And I know src=str3 is wrong but I've looked at various examples here and elsewhere on the web and cannot find the right format.  I've tried getElementbyId(str3) as I thought that gave the value of the variable but that is not right either.

Can anyone give me the correct format to pass this variable to the src.
Thx - Marie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery `attr` to set the image source to the url that you already got, but do this only after the page is loaded.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery) topic also.Don't forget to set an ID to the frame

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function(){
    {
    var str1="http://bitz.bz/mapplacencia";
    var str2="#17/16.51876129/-88.36937785";
    var src = str1+str2;
    $('#frame-id').attr("src", src);
    });
</script>

    <iframe id="frame-id" width='80%' height='500px' frameBorder='0' src='' "></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not the image (mobile-legend.png)that is causing the problem.  It is the second line where it displays the map page in the iframe.    <p class="centeredImage"><iframe width='80%' height='500px' frameBorder='0' src="str3"></iframe></p>

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. But it is the same way to do it

Comment: Including the jQuery library as suggested above makes this work.

Comment: @MarieCarrollRigby: yes, i assumed that you did this since i specified to use jQuery. Good thing it is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want an easy way to reference your iframe, so make sure to add an `id` to the iframe element.

Then, use jQuery to make sure the document is ready, and once it is, set the `src` on the iframe by selecting the `id` you set using jQuery.

Note, you didn't close your `<p>` in your initial example which could be causing issues.

Here's a full example of how this all should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var str1="http://bitz.bz/mapplacencia";
    var str2="#17/16.51876129/-88.36937785";
    var str3=str1+str2;
    $('#iFrameName').attr('src', str3);
})
</script>

<p>
     <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="http://hostbelize.com/hotmobile/general/mobile-legend.png" alt="" width="80% alt=" />
</p>
<p>
     <iframe id="iFrameName" width='80%' height='500px' frameBorder='0'></iframe>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does work - it doesn't solve my problem, but that is a different issue with Safari!  Thx.