# Jquery Image like .. image replace on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I would replace Pictures on mouseover.
I Found a nice script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery), but the problem is all images on the page get replaced.
This way i would filter the images while selecting. 
I added each picture the ending "_rep".
The code im using:

```
$("img")
  .mouseover(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_akt.png";
    $(this).attr("src", src);
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_akt.png", ".png");
    $(this).attr("src", src);
  });
```

Search for something like that:

```
$("img like %_rep%")
//code mouseover, mouseout
```

Comment: and the question is? if you want to replace just one specific image all the time instead of a regex just give the img an id

Comment: No there are more images and if it possible i would do it like in the question.

Comment: ok so provide a fiddle that shows the error and we'll try to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to replace images which end of names are _rep ?

In that case you can do that :

```
$('img[src$="_rep.png"]')
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i searched for. Thank you =).

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("img[src$='_rep.png']")
```

`[src]` means all tags with an `src` attribute. and `[src$='_rep.png']` means all tags with an src attribute ending with '_rep.png'

and take a look here https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/
I recommend you look through all different kinds of JQuery selectors in the provided link.