# Why this jQuery code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why this jQuery code doesn't work?
Thank you!
It doesn't change the src attribute, why? I belive that I have done a correct code but It still doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Primo script</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#due').click(function() {
        $('#due').attr('src', 'immagini/apple.jpg');          
    }); 
    </script>

    <h1>Primo script</h1>
    <p>Ci sar&agrave; una bella immagine; se ci si clicca sopra l'immagine cambier&agrave;.</p>

    <img src="immagini/ant.jpg" id="due" title="una formica">

    <hr>
</body>
```

Comment: put this code into end of body tag and also check your browser console

Comment: Place your script tag below your body. It won't be able to find `#due` at the start

Comment: Maybe this helps you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery

Comment: Why should i put the code into the end?

Comment: when page is loaded than code execute line by line so jquery load before your image tag so Jquery will not find your image tag

Comment: it is a good practice to add any jquery code within `document.ready function` in order to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>Primo script</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
    </head>
   <body>
    <h1>Primo script</h1>
            <p>Ci sar&agrave; una bella immagine; se ci si clicca sopra l'immagine cambier&agrave;.</p>
    <img src="immagini/ant.jpg" id="due" title="una formica">    
    <hr>
</body>
</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#due').click(function() {
         $(this).attr('src', 'immagini/apple.jpg');          
      }); 
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Inside the click handler this refers to as "#due". Therefore $(this).attr('src', 'your_image');

Comment: now its ok @roland