# How to change image src on success AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

the form:

```
<form  action="/user/updateProfilePicture" id="uploadPhotoForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <button class="btn btn-onetraffic btn-responsive btn-large">+Change photo</button>
      <input class="btn btn-onetraffic btn-responsive btn-large" style="opacity: 0; height: 34px; margin-top: -34px;" type="file" id="uploadPhoto" name="file" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

Div where I want to my image source to be changed:

```
 <div id="img-container">
   <img id="upSlika" src="#"/>
 </div>
```

I get my images url from server through JSON

I tried :

```
success:function(){
                    console.log("success");
                    $("#upSlika").attr("src", res.pictureUrl);
                },
```

res is response I get

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Comment: How does your `res` look like?

Comment: {"pictureUrl": "url"};

Comment: @Kotidrmakavez: added answer below....

Answer (score 1):

the success callback  must be like this:

```
 success: function (res) {  

          $("#upSlika").attr("src", res.pictureUrl);    

     }
```

Comment: try to console the res argument inside the succes function (console.log(res);)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
success: function (res) {  
      $("#upSlika").attr("src", res["pictureUrl"]);    
}
```

Comment: this works but when i refresh the page it dissapears for some reason. but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use .prop() on newer versions of jQuery.

```
success: function (response) {  
  $("#upSlika").prop("src", response.image);    
}
```

where response.image holds the image src.

In your ajax.php file you can add the src in the array as below example :

```
json_encode(array('status'=>'success', 'image'=>'/path/to/image.jpg') );
```