# Change a "href" and img "src" value on refresh using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the image and anchor link on refresh for my banners. I have 4 different banner images and 4 different links for each banner. So I need when user refresh the page each banner will load with own URL.

**HTML code :**

```
<div class="ad_body">
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/" target="_blank">
        <img src="images/banner/partner1.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the image source using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-using-jquery)

Comment: can you explain **each banner will load with own URL**

Comment: I mean every banner have unique url when user click on banner user will redirect to website.

Comment: I think we need to see more code. What have you tried and it didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add images sources you have in array then choose from this array randomly :

```
$(function(){
    var links = ["link1", "link2", "link3"];
    var arr = ["partner1.jpg", "partner2.jpg", "partner3.jpg"];
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length) + 0;

    $(".ad_body a").attr("href", links[random]);
    $(".ad_body img").attr("src", "images/banner/"+arr[random]);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But how can i change the anchor link with banner image?

Comment: You could add another array for links, check my update.