# JQuery change img src on hover doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the img src on hover with JQuery.
I am using Brackets, and when I run a live Chrome preview its all good.
But when I open the file directly on Chrome it doesn't work (same with IE).

My code:

```
$("#logo img").hover(
    function(){
              $("#logo img").attr("src","/images/img1.gif");
 }, function() {
              $("#logo img").attr("src","/images/img2.gif");
});
```

Edit:
This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="logo">
    <img id="logo-img" src="images/img1.gif" alt="logo">
</div>
```

The img tag has an id "logo-img", but using this id directly doesn't help:

```
$("#logo-img").hover(
    function(){
              $("#logo-img").attr("src","/images/img1.gif");
 }, function() {
              $("#logo-img").attr("src","/images/img2.gif");
});
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: please, post the html code that refers to #logo img... but I suggest you to give a class or id to the img to access it directly, like: $('.elementClass).hover

Comment: Please, give me the path of the file with the code and with img.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the image source on rollover using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540349/change-the-image-source-on-rollover-using-jquery)

Comment: Your id is not *really* valid? You can not use spaces in them. Also provide HTML for this. Your JQuery is fine.

Comment: Also are you providing the images in the correct directory when opening with chrome?

Comment: Please be more specific as of whart exactly doesn't work, and what happens instead. Here you are probably missing that the exchange `src` you are providing starts with a `/`, whereas the original `src` attribute doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. Try this:

```js
$("#myImage").hover(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "https://static.pexels.com/photos/54630/japanese-cherry-trees-flowers-spring-japanese-flowering-cherry-54630.jpeg");
}, function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "https://static.pexels.com/photos/207962/pexels-photo-207962.jpeg");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="myImage" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/207962/pexels-photo-207962.jpeg">
```

Try running it. It is probably a problem with your image ID. Also use `$(this)` to make it easier.

Comment: Youre welcome! Consider marking this as accepted answer by clicking the grey tick mark left of the answer under the downvote sign.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS

```css
img:hover {
  background: url("https://i2.wp.com/www.froutlet.com/store/i/user_icon.png?ssl=1");
  /* padding: [image-height] [image-width] 0 0 */
  padding: 200px 200px 0 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.vacul.org/extension/site/design/site//images/anonymous-user.png" />
```

Using JS

```js
$("#imghover").hover(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "https://www.vacul.org/extension/site/design/site//images/anonymous-user.png");
}, function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "https://i2.wp.com/www.froutlet.com/store/i/user_icon.png?ssl=1");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="imghover" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.froutlet.com/store/i/user_icon.png?ssl=1">
```